# How to Get Multiple elements to change color on hover CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I would like multiple elements of a certain item to change color when the user hovers over the text. Please view my site (http://www.codesrce.com) and hover over the "more" menu item. As you can see, only the more text changes colors to white when you hover over it, but the menu icon does not. Please view my source code and maybe give me a solution to my problem. I want to have it so that when the user hovers over the `<li>` that contains the more `<a>` and the more icon `<span>` then they will both change colors to white. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Also if possible, can I make it so that after the user hovers over it, and moves down to the menu below the element, make it remain white until the user leaves the menu? (Sorry if my wording is tricky)

HTML

```
<li class="MoreMenuContainer"><a href="#" class="MoreHyperlink">More <span class="MoreMenu"></span></a>
```

CSS

```
.MoreMenu {

text-decoration: none; 

font-size: 8px;

color: gray;

margin-top: 1px;

-webkit-text-stroke: 0.35px;

font-family: 'icomoon';

speak: none;

font-style: normal;

font-weight: 100;

font-variant: normal;

text-transform: none;

text-decoration: none;

-webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease;

-moz-transition: color 0.3s ease;

-ms-transition: color 0.3s ease;

transition: color 0.3s ease;
```

}

.MoreMenu:before {

```
content: "\e6b8";
```

}

Comment: What have you tried? It's asking a little much to have us look at your site and fix your problems for you. We're all here to learn, learn with us.

Comment: By the way your website is awesome! @Tyler McGinnis I looked at it and really appreciate all the hard work you put into it. Good work!

Comment: Also what is the font you used for your "I AM TYLER MCGINNIS" Header on your site? I like it. I looks like the font on (http://tympanus.net/codrops)

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. Another tip. Right click then select 'Inspect Element' then on the right side it says font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular', arial, helvetica;. So I used the LeagueGothicRegular font for it. :)

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the tip. I wasn't sure if the inspect element included css styles. Like I said, nice job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this maybe?

```
li:hover span, li:hover a {
    color:White;
}
```